# RSA over Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, jquery

The company i work for has found a problem working on a new page, in sending new/modified users passwords when the account is saved to server side code from client side using jquery ajax.
At the moment, the password is sent in plaintext to a webmethod in which it is processed and then encrypted server side before being sent to the database.

My major fear is a sniffer catching the traffic in the middle and taking the plaintext password, pretty logical problem.

My company does not use SSL/HTTPS therefore im looking at other encryption methods. 
The only person capable of changing passwords is the administrator, and the logged in user is capable of changing their own password. Therefore nobody else has access to that page without authentication.

Should i use a plaintext key in javascript with 3DES to send an encrypted password to server side and reduce the chances of a man in the middle attack,

Or should i use a public/private key system with RSA so that a generated public key is sent to clientside on post, that can only encrypt the data, and then server side containing the private key to decrypt the data when sent.

Obviously the user/ admin is always going to be able to debug and see their password in their webbrowser, but which is the better solution to prevent a man in the middle attack.

Ive read that rsa encryption can be quite hungry on resources to generate keys.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use SSL?

Comment: Can't someone just sniff the private key with RSA too?

Comment: In theory, but the company doesnt want to implement this at the current time.

Comment: The private key would stay on the server side aspx.vb page. How would this be sniffed out of curiousity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) to generate a key pair, and issue the public key to the client. The client could encrypt it using a usefull [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin [pidCrypt](https://github.com/jas-/jQuery.pidCrypt)

Back on the server, you could decrypt the sensitive data with the private key. We are actually doing something similar for our [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security) solution (in addition it running over HTTPS).

The following is a nice post by John Peterson showing how to do something similar and use [RSA with Web API](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/)

Hth.